# adding destination URL after current in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new wordpress site in it's own directory called Journal! and I am using a theme called This Way!

The problem I have is with my menu after I created a custom one it add the desination url after the current one much like this...

http://www.gekkodev.com/journal/#!https://www.gekkodev.com/

when it should direct to..

https://www.gekkodev.com/

any ideas?

Comment: I see you have changed your theme to twenty-twelve.  Can you post some code for your header/function?

Answer (score 0):

just add http:// before the url and check if the url has http://

```
if (strpos($user_url ,'http://')){
   echo $user_url;
}else{
   echo 'http://' . $user_url;
}
```

Comment: you can format code properly by adding 4 spaces before any line